# Как объявить несколько переменных @FXML

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea

```
@FXML
Button btn1;
@FXML
Button btn2;
@FXML
Button btn3;
```

это не очень удобно, хотелось бы не повторять несколько раз `@FXML`

Comment: эм простое перечисление "btn1, btn2, ... , btn_n"

Comment: Ой, плохой пример) допустим, что классы разные, Button,Label,TextField...

Comment: опять же если это одинаковые объекты, то перечислением (не силен в терминах), разные -> тут уж ничего не поделаешь, только так как показано выше

Answer (score 1):

```
    @FXML 
    private Button btn1;
    @FXML
    private Button btn2;
    @FXML
    private Button btn3;
```

Очень странно используете аннотацию.
@FXML (аннотация) используется для того, чтобы поля оставались приватные, но Ваши fxml видели данные поля.

Можно написать так:

```
    public Button btn1;
    public Button btn2;
    public Button btn3;
```